# found array with zero features

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression, data-science

I am a beginner to machine learning and just trying to build my first linear model. The error I am getting is,

*Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(284, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required* .

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong??

```
X = data.iloc[:,:-1]
Y = data.iloc[:,:8]
```

Comment: Try  `numpy.reshape()` or  `pd.DataFrame` to reshape your data set

Answer (score 0):

It says that you have 0 features for each entry because you're second dimension is indeed 0. You want to convert the array to the dimensions (284,1).

Comment: how can i convert the array  to the new dimension??